How to take care of Visited points (in 2D (x,y) ) in Java
In a subproblem, I want to get the total number of points in x-y plane i have visited. and every point must be unique. ie. if you have already visited (1,2) and if you again encounter this you won't count it again as it has been counted earlier when it was visited.
In java we don't have any container to store two variables together.(like in c++ we have pair)
so to store x and y for point i am using array of size 2. when i encounter any point, i store it's x and y value to new array and add it to hashset.
before adding it to hashset i check if hashset already contains any array holding same values.
but when i check for it using Hash_set.contains(temp_array) it gives false, even if there is same value containing array in hashset.
probably it's because contains method doesn't check for the values the array inside it contains.
please suggest any other way to do it.
i tried another way also by defining new class to store x and y. but same problem exist here as when i store x and y to object of this class and add it to hashset, i check for the same using contains() method but it gives false, even though there is the object with same x and y value.
please help me to take care of my visited points.
also tell how to we can make hashset of array or hashset of objects in which the contains() method works correctly.
HashSet<int[]> hs = new HashSet<>();
        int temp[] = {1,2};
        hs.add(temp);

        int curr[] ={1,2};
        System.out.println(hs.contains(curr));     //it gives false.

